Issue with Transparent PNG Texture in URDF Showing Black Background in RViz
I'm trying to apply a PNG texture with a transparent background to a box in my URDF file. The box should be see-through with only the texture visible. However, when I load the model in RViz, the transparent areas of the PNG are shown as black instead. Here is the relevant part of my URDF:
<robot name="test_robot">
    <link name="test_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.6038 1 0"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="MyTestMaterial">
                <texture filename="package://my_robot/media/materials/textures/icon.png"/>
                <color rgba="1 1 1 0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
    </link>
</robot>

The PNG file definitely has a transparent background. How can I make RViz properly display the texture with transparency?
